# Host a pure angular site using Asp.Net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I created an angularjs site using the seed project. What's the simplest way to host it using .Net core/Asp.net core?

Answer (score 0):

Use Kestrel and the static file middleware to serve the html, js, and css files.

Here's a simple startup file: https://github.com/aspnet/StaticFiles/blob/dev/samples/StaticFileSample/Startup.cs

Answer (score 0):

If you're hosting on Windows, I recommend you to [host your app on IIS](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html).

You can find more info about hosting [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/index.html).